# Silverlight Datagrid Databinding

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I'm a newbie to Silverlight and I'm having some trouble finding a solution to an issue.

I have a silverlight datagrid with 3 columns. One of the columns is bound to an integer. I want to be able to bind my column to a function that would translate my integer into it's status code. The function accepts an integer, and using a switch statement I return a string of what that number represents.

0 = Inactive
1 = Active
2 = Pending
etc

A lot of what I've found has been techniques for Element Binding, which is very cool, but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an IValueConverter that provides you the ability to invoke a function on the databound value.
You can customize the Convert method to return a string based on the value passed in :

> public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
>       {
>           switch((int)value)
>           {
>             case 0: return   "Inactive";
>             case 1: return   "Active";
>             case 2: return   "Pending";
>            }
>       }

[IValueConverter on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) 
 [IValueConverter example in Silverlight](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your architecture I would either

1. Implement an IValueConverter like Phani suggests
2. Use the Model-View-ViewModel(MVVM) pattern.  In this pattern, anything needed for the binding would be represented as addition property in your view model.

so you would have something like the following

```
public class ViewModel:INoftifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model _model;

    public string StatusCodeName
    {
        get
        {
            string statusCodeName = SomeCodeToGetStatusCodeNameFromStatus(_model.Status);
            return statusCodeName;
        }   
    }
}
```

You can then bind to this property

```
{Binding StatusCodeName}
```